# When I change the compatibility level from 120 to 130, I get the advantages of the version of 130?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a database from SQL Server 2014, so it has a compatibility version of 120.

I backup this database and I have restored in a SQL Server 2016.

If I change the version of the compatibility of the database from 120 to 130, do I get the advantages of the 130 version?

For example, [here I can see the differences between 120 and 130 versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx):

For example, the first difference is, in version 120 "The Insert in an Insert-select statement is single-threaded" and in version 130 is "The Insert in an Insert-select statement is multi-threaded or can have a parallel plan".

So if I change the version, the insert-select statements are single thread or multi-thread?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking about? BOL says "you will" and if you do not, file a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it means is that it can now create a parallel (multi threaded) plan for the insert in an insert-select statement, not that it always will be a parallel plan.  This is still a cost based decision made by the optimiser that depends on the query being run, the number of rows being returned, maxdop and cost threshold for parallelism settings etc.  It just gives an additional option rather than that portion always being serial.

Comment: Ok, I see, but if I change the database to 130 version, Is it able to use parallel queries if it is needed or not because really it is 120 version?

Comment: Yes it is able to use the new features because it is no longer running in version 120 mode, it is running in 130.